# BigQuery jobs.list API returns Internal Server Error

Tags: google-bigquery

When I try to use the jobs.list API (either using python script or the api explorer https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/list) there are times it returns 500 Internal Server Error.  This only happens when projection is set to full.  When projection is set to minimal the API returns job results as expected.  Do you know what is causing this and how do I get around this issue so that I can continue to extract all job history?  I need to get the full job details so that we can track GB processed by users.

Here is a sample of the error message:

500 Internal Server Error

- Hide headers -
- Cache-Control:  private, max-age=0, must-revalidate, no-transform
- Content-Encoding:  gzip
- Content-Type:  text/html; charset=UTF-8
- Date:  Mon, 06 Oct 2014 22:42:22 GMT
- ETag:  "GAZ7DK1jFQhf56anR-xA3uTt6Y0/Ij_si2vyu6tzwnz2XW8zN_FBOyM"
- Expires:  Mon, 06 Oct 2014 22:42:22 GMT
- Server:  GSE
- Transfer-Encoding:  chunked

Unknown Error

Comment: I was able to work around this issue.  It appears the error is related to something with the jobs[].status object.  When I exclude this from the results by limiting the fields returned in the fields filter I no longer get the failure.  Not sure what is being include in the jobs[].status that would cause this to fail.

Comment: Can you provide your project id? If you'd rather not post it in a public forum, can you e-mail it to tigani at google?